# how to sort columns in alphabetical order in kendo grid header column

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My Grid has a column menu, which contains displayed columns sub menu. I want to sort column in alphabetical order in kendo grid list but remember I do not want to sort column header.

I am able to see the columns in alphabetical order but when i tried to Hide any column from column menu it is hiding different column

Below is my code

```
columnMenu: true,

columnMenuInit:function(e){

              var container = e.container;
              var menu = container.find(".k-menu").data("kendoMenu");
              menu.bind("open", function(e){

                if($(e.item).hasClass("k-columns-item")){

                  var list= container.find('.k-columns-item ul');
                  var items = list.find('li');

                  list.empty();

                  items.each(function(x,y){
                    $(y).removeClass('k-first k-last')
                  });

                  items.sort(function(a,b){
                    a = $(a);
                    b = $(b);

                    var firstText = a.find('input[data-field]').attr('data-field');
                    var secondText = b.find('input[data-field]').attr('data-field');


                    return ((firstText < secondText) ? -1 : ((firstText > secondText) ? 1 : 0));

                  })

                  items.first().addClass('k-first');
                  items.last().addClass('k-last');


                  items.each(function(y,x){
                    list.append($(x));
                  })
                }
              });
```

Comment: Hey, Sam do you have some code you can share with us? Show us what you have tried and where its failing

Comment: I Have added code from below reference

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-sort-displayed-columns-menu-items

Comment: I have refreshed a few times and I cant see the code, can you check again for me

Comment: I am able to see the columns in alphabetical order but when i tried to Hide any column from column menu it is hiding different column

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-sort-displayed-columns-menu-items

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-sort-displayed-columns-menu-items

Comment: Hi Bill, are you able to see the code now?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Kendo bug.  See the URL below:
[kendo github issue link](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/5380)